# Drupal - Break up content with different content (After every 12 products, show an ad?)

Tags: php, drupal, view, taxonomy

Currently I have the homepage of a t-shirt site list a 4 column grid, each cell containing all the shirts on the website (using views). The client would like every few rows to display an ad (perhaps a random view/block item). Is this possible? I'm sure I will end up needing to set the grid display to something else but how could I program this in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be achievable by using views templates.

In your view display you can create custom tpl files. These can be found in the theme section (click on Information).

If you add a count to the foreach loop in the style tpl then after $i hits a certain number you can then print your ad or custom text.